# How to check if an item existing in one arraylist also exist in another arraylist?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

I am working on an app that gives near by restaurants in a list view and user can also store them in a favorite list. 
When the app is started, the near by places are loaded. I want to check if any near by places are there in favorite and if so then it should mark its checkbox(checkbox for marking a place as favorite).
It should check whether a near by place is already available in favorite list based on its name and if its is present, then its favorite checkbox should be checked.
Thanks in advance! :)
Here is my adapter code:

```
public class RestaurantAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PlaceDetailsClass>
{
Context context;
ArrayList<PlaceDetailsClass> placeDetailsClassArrayList;
ArrayList<PlaceDetailsClass> favouriteList;
private DatabaseHelper db;
public RestaurantAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<PlaceDetailsClass> placeDetailsClassArrayList)
{
    super(context, R.layout.restaurant_list_item, placeDetailsClassArrayList);
    this.context=context;
    this.placeDetailsClassArrayList = placeDetailsClassArrayList;
    db=new DatabaseHelper(context);
    Log.w("ArrayList in resAdapter",placeDetailsClassArrayList.toString());
    this.favouriteList = new ArrayList<>(db.getAllPlaces("restaurant"));
}
public static class Holder
{
    TextView nameTv;
    TextView vicinityTv;
    CheckBox favourite;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    final PlaceDetailsClass data = getItem(position);
    final Holder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        viewHolder = new Holder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.restaurant_list_item, parent, false);
        viewHolder.nameTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_restaurantname);
        viewHolder.vicinityTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_restaurantvicinity);
        viewHolder.favourite = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkbx_favourite);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    }
    else
    {
        viewHolder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.favourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if(viewHolder.favourite.isChecked())
            {
                db.addToFavourites(context.getString(R.string.restaurant), data.getName(),data.getVicinity(),data.getRating(),data.getLatitude(),data.getLongitude(),1);
                Toast.makeText(context,data.getName()+" "+context.getString(R.string.addToFav), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                db.removePlace(data.getName());
                Toast.makeText(context, data.getName()+" "+context.getString(R.string.removeFromFav), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    viewHolder.nameTv.setText(data.getName());
    viewHolder.vicinityTv.setText(data.getVicinity());
    if(data.getFavourite()==1)
    {
        viewHolder.favourite.setChecked(true);
    }
    else
    {
        viewHolder.favourite.setChecked(false);
    }
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount()
{
    return getCount();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position)
{
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return placeDetailsClassArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return position;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use apache collectionUtils and do something like this :

```
CollectionUtils.intersection(favoriteList, placeDetailsClassArrayList).forEach(place -> place.setIsFavourite(true));
```

Comment: Can you please post a link or something to learn more about it or if anywhere I can found a good example to refer. I am new to android so I am not familiar with it.

Comment: http://www.baeldung.com/apache-commons-collection-utils Here you can find snippets and such.

EDIT: Depending on which api level and java version you are using, you won't be able to use forEach on collections, but you can still store intersection as separate variable and iterate with for loop or iterator.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you really want to loop through the `ArrayList`, you can first get the value you want to search for. E.g. `theNameYouWantToLookFor`. Then just loop through it:

```
for(PlaceDetailsClass favourite : favouriteList) {
  if(favourite.getName().equals(theNameYouWantToLookFor)) {
    // Found, check the checkbox
  }
}
```

However, you don't really want to do this on the `UIThread`, and since you are using a database for these values, I would retrieve the favourites from the database immediately, and add some `boolean` to your `View` wether to make it `Visible` or not, based on the values in your database.

Comment: I am changing an int value in the object whenever a place is added to favorites. I am also retrieving the favorites list from database. When i am fetching a list of near by places, objects are having a 0 as their isFavorite value. It is changed to 1 when I am adding it to favorite and is being saved in database. I want the list should check from the database that whether it contains any place and if so then it should mark it as favorite.

Comment: You can just read that `int` value in `getView()`, like you are doing now. I don't see the issue here.

Comment: when i am removing anything from favorite and going to show all places, it is showing places as favorites which I have removed. It is not updating the array list retrieved from database at the starting.

Comment: I understand. Yes, then you can update the `ArrayList` using my method.

Comment: I am having an issue, when I am clicking on any of the item..the checkboxes are disappearing and then a corresponding activity is launched.

Comment: The toasts are showing whne adding or removing o favorites, but all the checkboxes are disappearing when an item in list is clicked and then the next page is opened.

Comment: If it solved your problem, please mark it as answer for other users. If your checkbox problem persists, please create a new question. :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you make another table in your database for storing the favorites. and saving the place id in it.

Then write a method in your database helper to check if that id exists in favorites table or not.

This SQL code might help you:

```
"SELECT * FROM favorites WHERE id =" + id
```

Comment: I thought of it, but it will make too many calls to the database everytime. The whole database will have to be traversed everytime for each object.

Comment: @YashMundra  I guess there wouldn't be a problem since you are using a local database. a lot of calls to database is a problem when you are using an online one.